# Heroku bot AttributeError: thread object has no attribute 'isAlive'

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, python-multithreading

Recently, I followed a tutorial on how to make a timeout function for my discord.py bot, so one of the commands wont take the bot too long. The command uses another script file, which is imported at the top of the `bot.py` code. When I ran the bot locally with `py bot.py`, the timeout works. But when I host the bot on Heroku, the command doesn't work. I looked to see if there was an error and used `heroku run bash` and then `python bot.py` and it produced this error when I typed the command on Discord:

```
Ignoring exception in command calculator:
Traceback (most recent call last):
(traceback...)

AttributeError: 'InterruptableThread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
(more traceback...)
```

The timeout function uses `threading` library. Here was the code for the timeout function:

```
def timeout(func, args=(), kwargs={}, timeout_duration=1, default=None):
    class InterruptableThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.result = None

        def run(self):
            try:
                self.result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                self.result = default

    it = InterruptableThread()
    it.start()
    it.join(timeout_duration)
    if it.isAlive():
        raise TimeLimitExpired()
    else:
        return it.result
```

I got this from the tutorial. I use the timeout function by doing

```
timeout(interpreter.visit, (ast.node, context), timeout_duration=TIMEOUT, 
default=RuntimeResult().failure("Execution timed out."))
```

and the variable `TIMEOUT` is 5. I am using Windows 10 and Python from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it` is an object of `InterruptableThread`, which inherits from `threading.Thread`. The `Thread` class does not have any attribute named `isAlive`, instead it has one called [`is_alive`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/threading.html?highlight=thread#threading.Thread.is_alive).

Change `it.isAlive` to `it.is_alive`.

Beware that python method names **usually** use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) and uses PascalCase for class names.

Comment: Many thanks... had to find this error installing R on ubuntu...